# PHP Not parsing rss using cURL properly

Tags: php, xml, rss

i just want to get the name of 'channel' tag i.e. CHANNEL...the script works fine when i use it to parse the rss from Google..............but when i use it for some other provider it gives an output '#text' instead of giving 'channel' which is the intended output.......the following is my script plz help me out.

```
$url = 'http://ibnlive.in.com/ibnrss/rss/sports/cricket.xml';
    $get =  perform_curl($url);
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml -> loadXML($get['remote_content']);  
  $fetch = $xml -> documentElement;
  $gettitle = $fetch -> firstChild -> nodeName; 
  echo $gettitle; 
  function perform_curl($rss_feed_provider_url){

       $url = $rss_feed_provider_url;
       $curl_handle = curl_init();

       // Do we have a cURL session?
       if ($curl_handle) {
          // Set the required CURL options that we need.
          // Set the URL option.
          curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
          // Set the HEADER option. We don't want the HTTP headers in the output.
          curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
          // Set the FOLLOWLOCATION option. We will follow if location header is present.
          curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
          // Instead of using WRITEFUNCTION callbacks, we are going to receive the remote contents as a return value for the curl_exec function.
          curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

          // Try to fetch the remote URL contents.
          // This function will block until the contents are received.
          $remote_contents = curl_exec($curl_handle);

          // Do the cleanup of CURL.
          curl_close($curl_handle);

          $remote_contents = utf8_encode($remote_contents);

          $handle = @simplexml_load_string($remote_contents);
          $return_result = array();
          if(is_object($handle)){
              $return_result['handle'] = true;
              $return_result['remote_content'] = $remote_contents;
              return $return_result;
          }
          else{
              $return_result['handle'] = false;
              $return_result['content_error'] = 'INVALID RSS SOURCE, PLEASE CHECK IF THE SOURCE IS A VALID XML DOCUMENT.';
              return $return_result;
          }

        } // End of if ($curl_handle)
      else{
        $return_result['curl_error'] = 'CURL INITIALIZATION FAILED.';
        return false;   
      }
   }
```

[php](/questions/tagged/php)

Answer (score 2):

`it gives an output '#text' instead of giving 'channel' which is the intended output` it happens because the `$fetch -> firstChild -> nodeType` is 3, which is a `TEXT_NODE` or just some text.  You could select channel by

```
echo $fetch->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0)->nodeName;
```

and

```
$gettitle = $fetch -> firstChild -> nodeValue;
var_dump($gettitle);
```

gives you

```
string(5) "
    "
```

or spaces and a new line symbol which happens to appear between the xml tags due to formatting.

ps: and RSS feed by your link fails validation at http://validator.w3.org/feed/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the XML - it's been pretty printed with whitespace so it is being parsed correctly. The first child of the root node is a text node. I'd suggest using [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/simplexml) if you want an easier time of it, or use [XPath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) queries on your DomDocument to obtain the tags of interest.

Here's how you'd use SimpleXML

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($get['remote_content']);
print $xml->channel[0]->title;
```